# Authenticity of an email in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have received an email from Mr. A. This email is on my Gmail account. But Mr. A does not confirm the email. What can I do to certify that the email is actually sent to me?

Comment: What do you you mean by "certify"? Why is not enough to check the sent to field? Do you already know about email headings? Please follow the [tour] and check out [ask] the learn part of the workings of this site.

Comment: In court Mr. A denies sending this email saying that I am making up with everything. How can I prove that this email was sent from Mr. A?

Comment: Since your are looking for legal advice, you should ask this to an specialized lawyer.

Comment: Maybe someone in https://law.stackexchange.com/ could help you.